# Blender/Python - Faces in AABB

Tags: python, blender

Is there a premade function that can be used in Blender through Python to determine if a face is inside an AABB?

I have a custom function that does it manually but since when I have plenty of faces to check it becomes a tad slow, so I was hoping if there was an internal function it will speed it up a bit.